# React/Typescript: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Here's my error that I got in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text, complete}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This is my code below:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

type FormElement = React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;

interface ITodo {
  text: string;
  complete: boolean;
}

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[]>([]);

  const addTodo = (text: string) => {
    const newTodos: ITodo[] = [...todos, { text, complete: false }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: FormElement): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo(value);
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {todos.map((todo: ITodo, index: number) => (
          <div key={index}>{todo}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById("app-root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

At first I thought there was a problem with my map but then I couldn't see any problem with it. Any idea what did I miss in the code?
It's pretty simple todo list app which at the moment the functionality is adding a todo and displays it on the screen underneath the input.

Comment: `<div key={index}>{todo}</div>`: `todo` is an object according to its interface. This isn't allowed (like the error says). If you're trying to print the text change it to `{todo.text}`.

Comment: @BrianThompson yes! Oh dear, silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to change from

`<div key={index}>{todo}</div>`

to

`<div key={index}>{todo.text}</div>` or `<div key={index}>{todo.complete}</div>`

inside your `todos.map` function, as `todo` is an object that cannot be rendered by React naturally.